# how to find a next minimum number after the first one?

Tags: c, codeblocks

So this is the code i writing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int total,i,j,n = 0,m,p,x;
  printf("How many items to buy : ");
  scanf("%d",&total);
  if (total%5 == 0){
    p = total/5;
    printf("You can get %d item free\n",p);
    total += p;
    printf("Now you have %d items to buy\n",total);
  }
  float number[total],price = 0,min = 0,discount = 0;
  for(i=0;i<total;i++){
        n = n+1;
        printf("Enter price %d : ",n);
        scanf("%f",&number[i]);
        price += number[i];
  }

    //This is the place I tried to find a discount//

  if(total<5)
    printf("Pay %.2f dollar",price);
  else{
    price -= discount;
    printf("Free %.2f dollar ,and pay %.2f dollar",discount,price);
  }
}
```

The task is

1.Every 5 items you will get 1 item for free

2.That free item have to be the lowest price in all item

for example : if your item price is 5,5,5,5,5,10. The total amount is 35 dollars and you will get 5 dollars for discount. The real price after discount is 30 dollars

But the problem that I found is If i buy 12 items. I will get 2 items for free. So how can I find another minimum price that I have to use for discount. I can find the first minimum price. But I tried to find another minimum but I failed to do that.

or like 3 items free. So i have to find 3 lowest price for discount

Comment: Sort the numbers in ascending order and read the second element?

Comment: Considering the `5,5,5,5,5,10` case, what is your expected answer for the "second minimum"? 5 or 10 (or another)?

Comment: @MikeCAT - five. In case of 12 items like 1,2 and 5,5,... ten times. i except discount to be 3 which is 1+2 and the final price is 50 dollars

Comment: @AchunSirakarun Or would it be the smallest price out of each group of 6, i.e. (1,2,5,5,5,5) -> 1 and (5,5,5,5,5,5) -> 5?

Comment: @dbush that is how I do when 1 item is free. But when there are more than 1 items is free. I don't know how to do it

Comment: The text seems to suggest that 6 items give 1 item discount, 12 items give 2 items discount, 18 items give 3 item discount and so on. However, your code doesn't use `6` but uses `5`. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

1.Every 5 items you will get 1 item for free

2.That free item have to be the lowest price in all item(s)

Sort the array `number[]` ([@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653193/how-to-find-a-next-minimum-number-after-the-first-one/68658628#comment121328589_68653193)), sum about the first 1/5 of them as discount, sum the rest as price.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const float *fa = a;
  const float *fb = b;
  return (*fa > *fb) - (*fa < *fb);
}

int main() {
  ...
  float number[total];
  // Read in costs
  ...

  // Sort the array
  qsort(number, total, sizeof number[0], compare);

  double discount = 0.0;
  for (int i= 0; i<total/5; i++) discount += number[i];
  double price = 0.0;
  for (int i= total/5; i<total; i++) price += number[i];

  printf("Free %.2f dollar ,and pay %.2f dollar", discount, price);
}
```

---

I see OP's discount scheme amiss though, as the "free" one should be the cheap one in every set of 5.

With sorted costs: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, I'd expect 2,7 are free.

```
  int set_count = 0;
  for (int i = total; i-- > 0; ) {
    set_count++:
    if (set_count < 5) {
      price += number[i];
    } else {
      discount += number[i];
      set_count = 0;
    }
  }
```